# Testcontainers can't pull ryuk image: quay.io is not reachable

Tags: testcontainers

I have been experiencing issue with testcontainers failing to pull "ryuk" image from quay.io.

```
[32m01:23:19.732[0;39m [35m[main][0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mo.t.d.a.AuthDelegatingDockerClientConfig[0;39m - Effective auth config [null] 
[32m01:23:30.281[0;39m [35m[tc-okhttp-stream-308592104][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36mc.g.d.a.async.ResultCallbackTemplate[0;39m - Error during callback 
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: {"message":"Get https://quay.io/v2/testcontainers/ryuk/manifests/0.2.3: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error"}
```

Comment: the action is here:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2763

Re-published the image to Docker Hub: qminder/moby-ryuk
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2763#issuecomment-635330300

Comment: There is an official container: https://hub.docker.com/r/testcontainersofficial/ryuk

Comment: yup, that seems to be the official alternative but still a temporary one :( 
https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/3816

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround is to use different ryuk container from DockerHub (https://hub.docker.com/r/testcontainersofficial/ryuk or https://hub.docker.com/r/qminder/moby-ryuk) by setting property in testcontainers property file `src/test/resources/testcontainers.properties`:

```
ryuk.container.image=testcontainersofficial/ryuk
```

Another option is to disable Ryuk in Testcontainers by setting environment variable `TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED` to `true` as described [here](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/).

Comment: thanks for posting, implementing the fix. For reference, here's the corresonding issue: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2763#issuecomment-635407953, which was just resolved.

Answer (score 18):

[Starting from version 1.14.3](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2763#issuecomment-636018118) `testcontainers` uses `ryuk` from Docker Hub instead of the quay.io. So raise your `testcontainers` version.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error recently: upgrading testcontainers to version "1.15.1" fixed this issue.

Comment: This also helps

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have solved this problem cleaning all my docker-images.

However, upgrading, my POM.XML, to test containers 1.15.1, already, is a solution to his trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by upgrading testcontainers to version 1.16.0